# Content added in article tags, doubling content, even without article content

Tags: views, nodes

I am displaying a content type through a view, using a contextual filter to limit results to one per page (nid). I believe this is a simple/standard way of displaying content, but being new to drupal I could be wrong.

My problem is that the content is duplicated. First within an 'article' tag, and then where I'd expect it to show up (inside the view tags).
I find it completely baffling because I don't even use the article content type. It's a problem I've had from the start, but I took the easy way out and simply hid the article content with display:none. 
But now, for some equally baffling reason, drupal has placed a new view I created inside the article tags - which of course means it doesn't show either. :-(

Why would drupal decide to send along my content inside the article tags?

I'm not sure if this is enough to go on, but I would be more than happy to provide more information.

Thanks for your time,
Tobias

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand at all what you are doing. I believe it's terminology problems, mainly because your use of the work "Tag" doesn't make sense to me at all. Duplicate results in Views is a common symptom of (mis)-using references between entities without understanding how they affect content lists.

Comment: I was talking about HTML tags. Sorry for not being precise there. I found my error though, which was incredibly stupid. I had given the content an url alias so as to function as a page, which would of course send along the content. I had then added a view as described above, adding the content once again. Silly me. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, otherwise this question will remain in the un-answered queue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments, I found my error:
I was talking about HTML tags. Sorry for not being precise there. I found my error though, which was incredibly stupid. 
I had given the content an url alias so as to function as a page, which would of course send along the content. I had then added a view as described above, adding the content once again. 
Silly me. Sorry for the inconvenience.